# How to get Objects scattered in the array fields based on the Ids which saved in the Js array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my database, there is a collection named `SetVoca`, its structure is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e63518c3e5d0d08980e2203"),
    "lessonId" : "5e63518c3e5d0d08980e2201",
    "vocaList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6351e43e5d0d08980e2207"),
            "word" : "a",
            "type" : "a",
            "meaning" : "a",
            "sente" : "a",
            "semean" : "a",
            "sug" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6351eb3e5d0d08980e2208"),
            "word" : "b",
            "type" : "b",
            "meaning" : "b",
            "sente" : "b",
            "semean" : "b",
            "sug" : "b"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6351be3e5d0d08980e2206"),
    "lessonId" : "5e6351be3e5d0d08980e2204",
    "vocaList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6351f63e5d0d08980e2209"),
            "word" : "c",
            "type" : "c",
            "meaning" : "c",
            "sente" : "c",
            "semean" : "c",
            "sug" : "c"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I now have ObjectId values scattered in the vocaList fields into an array as follows:

```js
const vocaIds = ['5e6351e43e5d0d08980e2207', '5e6351eb3e5d0d08980e2208', '5e6351f63e5d0d08980e2209']
```

Now I want to retrieve Objects scattered in the `vocaList` fields based on the Ids that I saved in the `vocaIds` array. I tried to code it like this:

```js
app.get('/saved-find', (req, res) => {
    SetVoca.find({ 'vocaList': { '_id': { $in: vocaIds } } }, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, so I should fix it to run it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your ids by wrapping them in ObjectId like this

```
const vocaIds = [mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5e6351e43e5d0d08980e2207'), mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5e6351eb3e5d0d08980e2208'), mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5e6351f63e5d0d08980e2209')]
```

And in query do like this

```
SetVoca.find({ 'vocaList._id': { $in: vocaIds } }, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```